# Adding a grandchild to a stacklayout via c# xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
stackRecentList.Children.Add(
                    new Frame {
                        BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                        Margin = new Thickness(30, 20, 30, 0),
                        Padding = new Thickness(10),
                        CornerRadius = 5,
                        HasShadow = true
                    }
                );
```

Basically I am adding a `<Frame>` to my stacklayout. I want to add a `<Label>` to that `<Frame>` there for it becomes the `<StackLayout>`'s grandchild. How do I do it in Xamarin Forms Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking a `StackLayout` has only its `Children` to care of, and it's now every child task to organize its own children. Now your frame has to care of its children by itself.

A Frame has a unique property: `Content`.

Follow this snippet to create your UI in code behind:

```
 Frame frame = new Frame
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                Margin = new Thickness(30, 20, 30, 0),
                Padding = new Thickness(10),
                CornerRadius = 5,
                HasShadow = true
            };

            var sl = new StackLayout();
            sl.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "test" });

            frame.Content = sl;


            stackRecentList.Children.Add(
                    frame
                );
```

I recommand you to add a `StackLayout` to Frame's `Content`(Do not add the `Label` to Frame's `Content` directly, If you have other controls want to add the Frame in later).

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is perfect. Sorry if it wasn't a good question, I'm very new to C# jumping from PHP